# EAP-TTLS Authentication

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection, wifi-configuration, internet-security, ttls

When I try to log onto some wifi networks on my laptop, after I enter the username and password, I'm asked for EAP-TTLS authentication, and prompted to enter a domain/username and a password/token. This doesn't happen on my phone  (which I am using to write this) or on anyone else's computer. I've tried entering the login information and just not entering anythimg, but I can't get it to connect. I suspect that some service that I cleverly installed on my computer is causing this, or perhaps a service that I cleverly disabled. I could be wrong, though. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What does the network use normally? EAP-PEAP?

Comment: I have no idea.